# msg": "failed to create temporary content file: timed out" ansible error

Tags: ansible

I am getting the following error:

```
  "url": "http://redrockdigimark.com/apachemirror/kafka/0.10.2.0/kafka_2.10-0.10.2.0.tgz", 
            "url_password": "****", 
            "url_username": "***", 
            "use_proxy": true, 
            "validate_certs": true
        }, 
        "module_name": "get_url"
    }, 
    "msg": "failed to create temporary content file: timed out"
}
    to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/kafka_install.retry
```

Answer (score 4):

As @marcv81 mentioned in his comment, you can try to increase the `timeout` for the `get_url` module (available since 1.8), as mentionned in [the documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/get_url_module.html)

```
- name: Download file
  get_url:
    url: http://redrockdigimark.com/apachemirror/kafka/0.10.2.0/kafka_2.10-0.10.2.0.tgz
    dest: /tmp
    timeout: 300
```

The timeout value is for the request call, not for the entire download

Answer (score 0):

What it feels like your task is getting timed out. You can increase the timeout in ansible config and rerun the play.

The default config file resides here `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`.

add the line below if it is not there otherwise edit it.

```
timeout = 60
```

Comment: @pavansai, If you are satisfied with the answer, can you please mark it as accepted so this question will be closed.

Comment: thanks mritunjay. I need one more help from you. How can i install an application in sudo user of remote server. When I run script with sudo user it is always saying authentication failure.

Comment: This answer is not correct. You need to increase the timeout of the get_url module call. The timeout in ansible.cfg is for establishing the SSH connection.